# Inverse image of a Tangent Bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

I'm reading a paper on harmonic maps and in it, it mentions the following. You can see the same notation on the wiki on Harmonic maps.

Let $ \phi : M \to N $ be a smooth map between two Riemannian Manifolds. Can someone briefly explain this notation: $ \phi^{-1}(TN) $?

Comment: I am not sure that this is what you are looking for. A smooth map $\phi: M \to N$ induces a map
$$T\phi: TM \to TN, (x,\xi) \mapsto (\phi(x),D_x\phi(\xi))$$

Comment: @57Jimmy Thanks a bunch! After some thought about reading a bit more on the paper and what you mentioned, I am sure that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page *[Harmonic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_map)* uses $\phi^{-1}TN$ to denote the [pullback bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle) of $TN$ via $\phi,$ otherwise written as $\phi^* TN.$ The differential $d\phi$ can be viewed as a section of the bundle $TM^* \otimes \phi^{-1}TN,$ since $d\phi(p)$ is a linear map $T_pM \to T_{\phi(p)}N$ and thus an element of $$T_p M^* \otimes T_{\phi(p)}N=(TM^*\otimes \phi^{-1}TN)_p.$$